# Can someone explain this jQuery toggle text method please?

Tags: jquery, text, toggle

I found this code online and works perfectly, I kind of get how it works but I'd like more information.

```
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Read More' ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More');
```

Please and thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are confused with the [ternary operator `? :`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

That's a short hand form of if else. The code you showing

```
$(this).text($(this).text() == 'Read More' ? 'Read Less' : 'Read More');
```

is equal to

```
if($(this).text() == 'Read More') {
  $(this).text('Read Less');
}else {
  $(this).text('Read More');
}
```